# Stokes' Theorem problem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $M \subset \mathbf{R}^n$ be oriented compact smooth $k$-manifold and $\alpha$ be a $C^1$ diferential $(k-1)$-form defined in a neighborhood of M. Use Stokes' theorem to prove that

\begin{align*}
   \int_M d\alpha = 0
\end{align*}

It looks like I have to apply Stokes' and then do something else but I don't what. I'm stuck with

\begin{align*}
   \int_M d\alpha = \int_{\partial{M}} \alpha
\end{align*}

Comment: Does $k$-manifold mean without boundary? Because then you are done.

Comment: No, it has boundary.

Comment: Thinking about $n=1$, $k = 1$, $M = [a,b]$, $\alpha$ is a $0$-form, then $\int^b_a d\alpha = \alpha(b) - \alpha(a)$, not zero in general, there has to be more conditions.

Comment: Shuhao beat me to it. I was in the middle of saying take $\alpha=x$ on $[0,1]$, then $\int_M d\alpha= \int_0^1 dx=1\neq 0$.

Comment: @Eduardo: Are you absolutely sure that it has _non-empty_ boundary? Because I think the problem is assuming that $M$ is without boundary (i.e $\partial M = \emptyset$).

Comment: By any chance that you writing $C^1$ differential $(k-1)$-form means that $\alpha = \mathrm{d} \gamma$ for some $\gamma$?

Comment: @Jesse I'm not completely sure about that but I'm assuming it since the problem statement doesn't talk about the boundary at all. Shuhao, there doesn't have to be necessarily such a $\gamma$ differential $(k-2)$-form.

Comment: @ShuhaoCao You're example seems to be right, though the problem doesn't name any other conditions.

Comment: I guess, it's meant that it doesn't have a boundary. But then, you might also have to *project* down $\alpha$ and $d\alpha$ to (the tangent of) $M$ in $\Bbb R^n$, since $\alpha$ is locally a $(k-1)$-from in $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: I concur with @Berci .